# Metasploit payload not working on Android 10

Tags: android, metasploit

I tried to create a payload using **`msfvenom`** and it doesn't work on ***Android 10***...
What can be the possible reason and how to prevent it?

And I used **`Metasploit`** on **`Termux`** to do it so is that a problem?

Comment: It's sure it has nothing to do with using Termux...

Comment: What else do you think is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [msfvenom payload problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104303/msfvenom-payload-problem)

Comment: If not, please provide more details, like what does "it doesn't work" mean? In what way does it not work?